# What's the best practice java package to put a Grails plugin's Groovy classes in?

Tags: plugins, grails, packaging

I'm building a Grails plugin.  I have a few Groovy classes in `$pluginDir/src/groovy`.  Grails apps that use this plugin will be instantiating these classes, so the class name and package name matter.

Is there a best practice as to what java package to put these classes into?  I don't want to put them into the default namespace; the classes names are fairly generic and could easily collide with other classes.

I'm hoping it's something like `org.grails.plugin.myPluginName`, but I haven't found any documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grails.plugin.xxx is an unofficial but recommended standard decided by the community

Reference

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Package-name-for-plugins-td4644160.html
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Plugin-namespaces-td2294738.html

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few of different package structures.

```
grails.plugin.myPluginName
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.myPluginName
```

The latter generally for plugins written by someone on the SpringSource team, like the spring-security-core plugin.  The former is for Greenmail.  If I were you, I'd look at several existing plugins, and pick the one that feels right for you.

Comment: Thanks -- I had seen the org.codehaus one and it didn't feel right because I'm not part of org.codehous.  I'll go with grails.plugin.